# Git Folder deleted in remote doesn't delete local on pull

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

One of my collages reorganized one of our projects in Git, which resulted in several of the directories that were there previously being deleted. When I pulled from development this morning using Source Tree the files in the directories that were deleted are gone, but the directories persisted on my local copy. Is there a way that when something like this happens that the directory can be deleted on pull?

This may be a duplicate question, but everything that I can find is addressing recovering deleted files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git tracks files, not directories. So to git, an empty directory just does not exist.

However you can use the `git clean -df` command to delete all untracked files and directories. Be careful though as this will delete any untracked *files* as well.

From the man pages:

```
Cleans the working tree by recursively removing files that are not under version control, starting from the current directory.

Normally, only files unknown to Git are removed, but if the -x option is specified, ignored files are also removed. This can, for example, be useful to remove all build products.

If any optional <path>... arguments are given, only those paths are affected.

-d

    Remove untracked directories in addition to untracked files. If an untracked directory is managed by a different Git repository, it is not removed by default. Use -f option twice if you really want to remove such a directory.

-f, --force

    If the Git configuration variable clean.requireForce is not set to false, git clean will refuse to delete files or directories unless given -f, -n or -i. Git will refuse to delete directories with .git sub directory or file unless a second -f is given.

-i, --interactive

    Show what would be done and clean files interactively. See "Interactive mode" for details.

-n, --dry-run

    Don't actually remove anything, just show what would be done.
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, shame that there isn't an option to only delete empty directories when doing that, as that would also delete all the downloaded node modules if this is an angular app.

Comment: A possible alternative would be to write your own bash script that finds and deletes empty directories in the project and run it in a post-merge hook.